# how to detach a disk when you cannot log into an instance

Tags: google-compute-engine

There is a disk attached to one VM instance - does deleting the disk delete its contents or does it just detach the disk.
I would like to attach this disk to another VM instance that I am able to log into and the disk I am interested in attaching doesn't show as possible option to attach. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

**[Deleting the disk](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/disks/delete) will delete it thus destroy it's contents and you won't be able to recover the data stored on that disk !**

If you want to [attach the disk to another instance](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/attach-disk) you have to stop the VM the disk is attached to, detach it and attach to the other one.

Another approach is to [create a disk snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots), then [create a new disk from disk snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) (wchich will be a copy of the  original one) and attach that disk to second instance.

You can use both console or `gcloud` for this.

In my opinion creating a snapshot and a new VM using it as an image for a new disk is much safer because you are working on a copy.